# Tablet stuck in "Recoery is not SEAndroid enforcing" and cannot turn off

Tags: rooting, samsung, odin, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

Just bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab A6 tablet T-580.

When I buy an Android device I do two things, immediately: 1) get latest OTA update without fully setting the device up (e.g. only Wifi, no Google account), and 2) root, then reformat and reconfigure

I have tried to follow [this guide](http://axeetech.com/2016/05/13/how-to-root-galaxy-tab-a-10-12016-t580-on-android-6-0/) and flashed the linked package with Odin.

Anyway after flashing the device is stuck in the boot logo with the above red error. I can't turn the tablet off.

However I had re-entered Odin mode with a lucky combination of PWR+Home+VDown and re-flashed the binary. However same problem.

Is there anything I can do, including re-flashing a completely stock binary, and try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't enable **OEM unlocking** in developer mode, go to sammobile download your stock firmware (Or do it with smartswitch emergency upgrade and initialization via downloade mode) and reflash stock.

Then when you are ready to root just enable **OEM Unlocking** in developer options.

Comment: I did it when I enabled USB debug. But ok let's go to sammobile and/or smartswitch

Comment: I remmeber that with my Nexus 6 I also had to "fastboot oem unlock"

Comment: Sir, is it correct to select the "HOME_CSC_ITV......." file for flashing in "CP"? I have some difficulties understanding the new Odin. I used to work fine with the one for SGS3 (3.6 perhaps)

Comment: Accepted answer as I finally managed to get the tablet back. Unfortunately, according to research about **similar** tablets, the bootloader could be impossible to unlock. The best I can do if I can't root the device is to kindly return the device to the seller reporting that I do not want to operate any Android device I can't have full control of